# Scala generics implementing Ordered[A[B]] gives strange compiler errors

Tags: scala, generics

I have strange error message, and I cannot fix it with `asInstanceOf[T]`

```
 trait ABase {
    type A <: ABase
    def compare(that: A): Int
  }

  case class B [A <: ABase] (someField: A) {
    //extends Ordered[B[A]] {
    def compare1(that: B [A]): Int = someField.asInstanceOf[A].compare(that.someField.asInstanceOf[A])
    /*Error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: _1.A where val _1: A
    = someField.asInstanceOf[A].compare(that.someField.asInstanceOf[A])*/
    def compare2(that: B [A]): Int = someField.compare(that.someField.asInstanceOf[A])
    /*Error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: B.this.someField.A
    = someField.compare(that.someField.asInstanceOf[A])*/
    def compare3(that: B [A]): Int = someField.compare(that.someField)
    /*Error: type mismatch;
 found   : that.someField.type (with underlying type A)
 required: B.this.someField.A
    = someField.compare(that.someField)*/
  }
```

Error itself

> Error: type mismatch;
>    found   : A
>    required: _1.A where val _1: A

Comment: SO questions should not include gists, but rather have the code embedded in the question. SO parser works fine here ;)

Comment: You are comparing an `A` to a `B[A]`, you should reformulate your question and explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Nope, I'm not. And error messages show that clearly. Cannot say it any clearer...

Comment: I were unable to format my code properly, I don't see an option for markdown or any html editor in here. So I constantly got errors from SO parser

Comment: @KostyaCallmetofindout When you edit, there is a button called `code sample`. It looks like two curly braces {}. You select your code and press it. Never've been easier (to be honest I saw it only after two years of SO. I was formatting my code manually before :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by casting to B's (this) `someField` type:

```
trait ABase {
  type A <: ABase
  def compare(that: A): Int
}

case class B [A <: ABase] (someField: A) {

  def compare1(that: B [A]): Int = someField.compare(that.someField.asInstanceOf[this.someField.A])

  def compare2(that: B [A]): Int = someField.compare(that.someField.asInstanceOf[this.someField.A])

  def compare3(that: B [A]): Int = someField.compare(that.someField.asInstanceOf[this.someField.A])
}
```

You can also keep a type attribute to make it more concise:

```
case class B [A <: ABase] (someField: A) {

  type ThisA = this.someField.A

  def compare1(that: B [A]): Int = someField.compare(that.someField.asInstanceOf[ThisA])

  def compare2(that: B [A]): Int = someField.compare(that.someField.asInstanceOf[ThisA])

  def compare3(that: B [A]): Int = someField.compare(that.someField.asInstanceOf[ThisA])
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. But does it look strange to me only ? Doesn't seem like a good practice - more like some compiler hack side effect.