# Local variables with the same type( generic type parameter) have incompatible type

Tags: scala, generics

This issue is related to compiler behavior described in another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038260/scala-generics-implementing-orderedab-gives-strange-compiler-errors)

I think this is related to the way generics are implemented in compiler, and it has something to do with Inner Class compiler feature. I've a similar question and I know that this could be fixed with

```
if(m.compare(lowerBound.asInstanceOf[m.Measure]) >= 0) {
```

But I don't want to cast same type to same type all over my code. There should be good explanation why this happens. Should I fill in compiler bug somewhere ?
Without local variable m - error messages get even more weird.

```
trait MeasureBase {
  type Measure <: MeasureBase
  def compare(that: Measure): Int
  def score: Double
}
case class DocTerm[Measure <: MeasureBase]
(val docID: Long, val measure:Measure)
  extends Ordered[DocTerm[Measure]] {
  def score = measure.score
  def compare(that: DocTerm[Measure]): Int
  = measure.compare(that.measure.asInstanceOf[measure.Measure])
}

   class WriteCacheIterator[Measure <: MeasureBase]
    (data:mutable.ArrayBuffer[DocTerm[Measure]]) {
      var position = 0
      def Next(lowerBound:Measure):Option[DocTerm[Measure]] = {
        if(position < data.size - 1){
          val m:Measure = data(position).measure
          val b:Measure = lowerBound
          if(m.compare(b) >= 0) {
            //gives compiler error 
            //Error:(39, 20) type mismatch;
            //found   : b.type (with underlying type Measure)
            //required: m.Measure
            //if(m.compare(b) >= 0) {
          }
        } else return None
      }
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide all the code. What is `DocTerm`? What is `compare`?

Comment: I can rewrite this code as to remove all the details that are not needed to reproduce compiler behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different definitions for `Measure`:

- the type parameter in `DocTerm` and other places, which is a subtype of `MeasureBase`.
- a type member inside `MeasureBase`.

The two have nothing in common (except the name, but they are really different things). There is nothing linking your generic `Measure` inside `WriteCacheIterator` to the type member called `Measure` inside each and every element in your `ArrayBuffer`. You need to refactor the code to make this constraint explicit.

You could probably refactor the code to only use type parameters (generics) everywhere.

```
trait MeasureBase[Self <: MeasureBase[Self]] {...} 
case class DocTerm[M <: MeasureBase[M](val docID: Long, val measure: M)
...
```